# Iconos en instalador aplicación java

Tags: java, netbeans

Estoy realizando un instalador para una aplicación que he desarrollado en Java. La creación del instalador la realizo con el programa Inno Setup Compiler 5.6.1.

Tengo bastantes problemas al asignar los iconos de mi aplicación: 
 - En primer lugar, he conseguido que el instalador .exe tenga un icono. Pero soy incapaz de asignar un icono a la aplicación una vez instalada. 
 - Necesito que el acceso directo que se crea en el escritorio y en el menú inicio tenga un icono, pero no se cómo hacerlo. 
- También necesito, que al abrirse la aplicación, aparezca el icono en la barra superior de la aplicación, pero tampoco lo consigo. He colocado el siguiente código en el código de mi aplicación:

```
         Image image = new ImageIcon("icono2.png").getImage();
         this.setIconImage(image);
```

Si ejecuto la aplicación desde NetBeans, sí me aparece el icono superior, pero luego desde el jar que se crea en el directorio dist ni tampoco cuando instalo con el instalador, aparece ese icono.

Agradecería un poco de ayuda al respecto.

Gracias por adelantado.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando la siguiente sentencia coloco los iconos en mis aplicaciones:

`this.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("nombreicono.extension")).getImage());`

Según he estado viendo por encima, el icono que colocas en el instalador con *Inno Setup Compiler* es independiente del .jar.